# Flow: "Is Null" does not work for compound fields?

Tags: visual-workflow, null, compound-fields

I have a record-triggered Flow on Contact where I want to check if the MailingAddress is null.  However, the decision element doesn't work if I use a criterion of Record.MailingAddress Is Null FALSE.  Instead, I have to test the individual fields like MailingStreet.

The criteria in the screenshot are joined by OR.  The flow works with this criteria, but does not work if I remove the MailingStreet criterion.

[image]

I don't understand this because [the documentation says](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/compound_fields_limitations.htm) compound fields can be used with ISBLANK in formula fields.

Do I have to use a formula variable as a workaround here?

Comment: If the docs say something is supported, but it's not in practice, then you should be logging a bug. Of course, having this question here gives the issue visibility, but we probably can't provide much more of an answer than "contact support."

Comment: It does work (`ISNULL(BillingAddress)`) within a validation rule even if you fill only one field within the compound field, it evaluates to `false`. As sfdcfox said, support case is best to get it confirmed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I opened a case with Salesforce support and they said Flow decision criteria do not support compound fields.  However, in their testing they discovered that Flow formula variables do not support compound fields either, which they  identified as a bug (ID W-9692286) and are working on a fix.